# Twitter Bootstrap centering button text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that adding `text-center` to div classes is sufficient for centering a group of buttons. But in my situation I need to center the text inside the buttons.

I tried to add margin-left, margin-right, text-center. But didn't help.
Is it possible to center the text ?

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg text-center"
        style="width:48px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Ad</a>
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/YXrRT/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-left:0; padding-right:0`

Answer (score 1):

You padding on the buttons is too large (16px horizontally). Try changing the padding to `10px` or less.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YXrRT/4/)

Also you should consider using CSS classes instead of `style` attributes to avoid repetition.

Comment: Eventually I will add them to css file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
```

from

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg text-center" style="width:48px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Pp</a>
```

Comment: The problem is padding related, removing the margin will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give any custom CSS like width and margins remove them and it will work. You use Bootstrap so you don't have to use custom stylings for buttons

Comment: I need to get all buttons have same width. So I use style-width. If I don't use width this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/YXrRT/5/

Answer (score 0):

check the `jsfiddle`,you should remove margin-left:auto,margin-right:auto inline code

`http://jsfiddle.net/YXrRT/6/`